# Integration $ \int x^2 \cos(nx) dx $

Tags: integration

How do I solve this integral?

$ \int x^2 \cdot \cos(\frac12 n\pi x)dx $

I tried integration by parts...

$ u=x^2\\u'=\frac13 x^3\\v'=\cos(\frac12 \pi n x)\\v=sin(\frac12 \pi n x)\cdot \frac12 \pi n $

$ \int x^2 \cdot \cos(\frac12  nx)dx=x^2\cdot sin(\frac12 \pi n x) -\int \frac13 x^3\cdot sin(\frac12 \pi n x) dx $

I don't get any further from here...

Comment: Well you are in the right track! How about starting IBP with the trig. function first?

Comment: there is mistake in second line , it should be $u'=2x$

Comment: You choose the initial $uv$ wrong. So $$v = x^2\\u' = \cos (\frac{n}{2}x)$$ also be careful when integrating trig function.

Comment: you are integrating when you should differentiate and conversely.

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of $n\pi x/2$ to begin with, doing the substitution
$$
t=\frac{1}{2}n\pi x
$$
that gives
$$
x=\frac{2t}{n\pi}\qquad dx=\frac{2}{n\pi}\,dt
$$
so the integral becomes
$$
\left(\frac{2}{n\pi}\right)^3\int t^2\cos t\,dt
$$
We can leave out momentarily the constant and integrate by parts twice:
\begin{align}
\int t^2\cos t\,dt
&=t^2\sin t-\int 2t\sin t\,dt\\
&=t^2\sin t-2\left(-t\cos t-\int-\cos t\,dt\right)\\
&=t^2\sin t+2t\cos t-2\sin t+C
\end{align}
It should be easy to reinstate the constant and do the back substitution.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** (starting IBP using the trig. function first)

$$\begin{align*}
\int x^2 \cos \left ( \frac{1}{2}n x \right )\, {\rm d}x &= \frac{2}{n} x^2 \sin \left ( \frac{1}{2}n x \right )  - \frac{4}{n}\int x \sin \left ( \frac{1}{2}n x \right )\, {\rm d}x \\ 
 &= \frac{2}{n} x^2 \sin \left ( \frac{1}{2}n x \right ) + \frac{8}{n^2} x \cos \left ( \frac{1}{2}nx \right )  + \frac{8}{n^2}\int \cos \left ( \frac{1}{2}n x \right )\, {\rm d}x \\ 
 &=\cdots 
\end{align*}$$

Final result accoring to W|A is:

$$\int x^2 \cos \left ( \frac{1}{2}n x \right )\, {\rm d}x = \frac{2 [\left ( n^2x^2 -8 \right )\sin \frac{nx}{2} +4nx \cos \frac{nx}{2}]}{n^3}+ c , \;\; c \in \mathbb{R}$$

*I highly doubt that I have not made a calculation error in the previous calculations. If so, feel free to correct me.*

**P.S:** A general tip when dealing with integrals of trig. functions and polynomials is that you begin IBP with the trig. first and you appply IBP so many times as the degree of the polynomial.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Combine the identities
$$(x^2\sin(nx))'=2x\sin(nx)+nx^2\cos(nx)$$
$$(x\cos(x))'=\cos(nx)-nx\sin(nx)$$
$$(\sin(nx))'=n\cos(nx)$$
 to cancel out the unwanted terms.